# Размер таблицы битрикс b_perf_sql

Tags: битрикс

Очень быстро наполняется таблица базы данных Битрикс b_perf_sql в которой собираются запросы к sql. Из-за чего может быть такое излишне быстрое наполнение и как его победить?

Подозреваю, что проблема в нестандартных запросах к базе данных. Но, может, это какой-то нехороший симптом?

Comment: пожалуйста прочитайте [как задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), и укажите конкретную причину с чем вам помочь. на глаз проверьте соответствие настроек сервера требованиям битрикса с помощью встроенного инструмента `Настройки->Инструменты->Проверка системы`, выполните `Проверку БД` (`Настройки->Инструменты->Диагностика->Проверка БД`) и `Оптимизацию БД `(`Настройки->Инструменты->Диагностика->Оптимизация БД`). Возможно следует более тонко настроить конфиг mysql или другой используемый сервер.

Comment: И еще хорошо бы уточнить, в мегабайтах в сутки, скорость наполнения и общий размер таблички в итоге.

Comment: Нашел. Все удивительно просто: Это логирование SQL запросов. Настройки модуля - Монитор производительности - Вести журнал SQL запросов - Галочку снять, если стояла.